# Issue with QLineEdit clear signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-necessitas

I'm working with the [Qt KDE Necessitas](http://necessitas.kde.org/) project. I have a project built in Qt Creator and I am installing the `apk` on an emulator API-15 (also tested on API-10).

The following code is setup to clear the text of two different `QLineEdit` objects when a button is clicked, but this isn't the case. Randomly, only one of the two `QLineEdit` objects are cleared.

mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
public slots:
    void slotClear();

private:
    QLineEdit* line1;
    QLineEdit* line2;
//...
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QFormLayout* form = new QFormLayout;
    line1 = new QLineEdit;
    form->addRow(tr("Line 1: "), line1);
    line2 = new QLineEdit;
    form->addRow(tr("Line 2:"), line2);

    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton;
    mainLayout->addLayout(form);
    mainLayout->addWidget(button);

    QWidget* centralWid = new QWidget(this);
    centralWid->setLayout(mainLayout);
    this->setCentralWidget(centralWid);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slotClear()));
}

void MainWindow::slotClear()
{
    line1->clear();
    line2->clear();
}
//...
```

Calling the function `QLineEdit::setText("")` produces the same results. Additionally, connecting the `clicked()` signal from the button directly to the `clear()` slot of the `QLineEdit` has no effect.

I haven't been programming in Qt for very long, so I am unsure if there is something I am doing wrong. Is anybody seeing something needs to be corrected in order to have the text cleared from BOTH QLineEdits? I am not sure if this is unique to Qt itself or Qt Necessitas. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I have also just noticed that entering text in one line, switching to another line and entering text there, and then switching back to the original line results in the original text being erased once the field is clicked (note, the button was never clicked). I think this is a pretty clear indication that something funky is going on.

**EDIT 2**

[Registered as a bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=309779) with KDE

Comment: Does calling update() on the line edits and/or on the main window itself change anything?

Comment: @RA.: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: FWIW, I've verified that the code you've posted works correctly on a desktop machine.  Unless there's some other code causing the problem, then this looks like it's unique to Necessitas.

Comment: @RA.: Good info, thanks :). I think I'm going to register this as a bug.